# How to set text validation?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to only allow text input on some cells. I have tried some code, but it allows to input numbers and letters. Any help would be great, thanks.

I tried the `istext` function and it works. When the input is all numbers it does not allow, but in number/letter case is does not work

```
  =ISTEXT(D6)
```

Comment: So you don't want numbers to be allowed at all, is that right?

Comment: if it posible, neither special characters

Comment: In that case, you will be best served by Scott's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This formula used in data validation will only allow alpha(a-z) and no others:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")))=LEN(A1)
```

Comment: I asume A1 is where I would put the validation, right?

Comment: When you select the range to set your data validation, the first cell is highlighted in a different color. Use that cell address in place of A1 in this formula.

Answer (score 3):

You need a formula that returns false when there are numbers in the cell, you can normally use:

```
=COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},D6))=0
```

But in your case, you must place the formula inside a data validation rule, and those don't allow array constants, so you'll have to use repeated `Find` statements:

```
=COUNT(FIND("0",D6),FIND("1",D6),FIND("2",D6),FIND("3",D6),FIND("4",D6),FIND("5",D6),FIND("6",D6),FIND("7",D6),FIND("8",D6),FIND("9",D6))
```

Comment: But this will not stop other non alpha characters.

Comment: You're right, but I'm not even sure whether that's the user's intention from the short question they wrote.

Comment: True, you may be correct and the user may want other things besides just alpha.  i was always taught to find what you want not what you don't want.  Either way the OP is covered.

Comment: Thankls for the reply! I just want letters